# cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'loading', как исправить?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, opencart, jquery-ui, opencart3.x

OpenCart 3
Ошибка cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'loading' при оформлении заказа 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У меня был отключен bootstrap.js, после его подключение всё заработало.

Comment: “Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.”

Comment: @finally почему же, вполне себе ответ.